# BlackBerry - App on store already; can I change code signing keys

Tags: blackberry

We built an app for a client some time back, signed it with our company keys, and put it up on the BlackBerry App World store for them.

We have since terminated our contract with the client.

They have now done further (in-house) dev on the app, and asked us for our signing keys so they could sign it. The answer to that request is a very loud "NO!".

My question is:

- If they apply for a **new signing key**, and sign the new version with that key, will they be able to upload the new app & replace the current one on the App World? i.e. as **version 2.x**

(Or does the key identify the app? e.g. on Android you must sign your apps with the same key in order to submit a new version)

Comment: good question. as scubaza said , You can sign the app with which ever keys supplied by RIM. The update will go through without a problem. The keys are used to verify the integrity and authenticity of your application, while in android land,  it would mean you need to use the same key so you can update the app

Comment: Signing key does not identify the application. It does not contain inside any information related to key owner like company name, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently changing the signing key is not a problem:

[Does the signing key for an app have to match the vendor?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-App-World-Development/Does-the-signing-key-for-an-app-have-to-match-the-vendor/td-p/1367251)