# Can we use different certificates for updating Blackberry Application?

Tags: blackberry, publishing, sign

I have developed a Blackberry Application and requested Blackberry for Signing Certificates, where in I have entered my Company Details. Then I have published the App on my client's Vendor portal but the app is shown on the name of company but when it is being installed, it is showing my company name instead of client company name. Will the blackberry devices shown the company details which are entered during the certificate generation? if so how can I publish another update with new certificate. Will Blackberry app world accept the update that is signed with different certificate? As I am from Android Background, I don't know this details.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is that, in the device settings/options, you're seeing this screen

[image: Options Screen Example]

with the name of your company (where my screenshot says **BlackBerry Developer**), that's not a result of using *your* code signing keys.  It's probably a default in your (Eclipse) development environment, and you can change it without changing code signing keys.

Open up the `BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml` file, and change the **Vendor:** field to be your client company's name, not your company's name.  In the xml, it will look like this:

```xml
<Properties ModelVersion="1.1.2">
  <General Title="" Version="1.0.0" Vendor="MyCompany" Description=""/>
```

If you're talking about which company name is listed in the BlackBerry World **store**, that should be defined by what values you enter into the app (or vendor) description in the Vendor Portal.

Code signing keys are really just used by BlackBerry to identify who (which 3rd-party developers) are using protected APIs ... not to identify the apps' vendors to the users.  This way, if apps are found to be using those APIs maliciously, BlackBerry will know which developer wrote the malicious code.

If you still want to know if you can change signing keys (out of curiousity), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10024208/119114).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the for the versions 5,6,7 it works. But wwe don't have any Blackberry_App_Descriptor.xml for Android porting apps. then how to put the vendor name over there?

Comment: @TNR, Ok, so just to clarify, are you asking about OS 5, 6, 7, or are you asking about the Android runtime for BlackBerry 10?

Comment: @TNR, I don't develop for BlackBerry 10, but [from this document](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/converting_apk_to_bar_files_1766001_11.html), it looks like if you're trying to simply convert an Android .apk to a BlackBerry 10 .bar file, `apk2bar` takes a `-a` argument.  But, for the sake of others reading this question, please let us know whether you're using the old BlackBerry Java platform, or BlackBerry 10 / Android.  Thanks.